# linq query, convert sql query to linq  for VB.net

Tags: linq

I am trying to get fields from one table and max(expirationDate) from another table.  This is my original linq query:

```
                            tanks = (From t In db.Table1 _
                            Where t.CompanyID = txtCompanyID.Text.Trim() _
                            Join d In db.Table2 On t.TankID Equals d.TankID
                            Order By d.ExpireDate Descending
                            Select t).ToList
```

that brings back multiple expireDates, I only want the max(expireDate) for each record

The following sql query works, I just need to put it into a linq query

```
    select t1.*,
(Select MAX(Table2.ExpireDate) 
from Table2 as t2 
where t2.TankID = t1.TankID) 
as max_expire_date
      from Table1 as t1 
      where t1.CompanyID = '5467'
      order by t1.CargoTankID
```

Does anybody know how to get this into linq?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
tanks = db.Table1.Where( t => t.CompanyId == txtCompanyID.Text.Trim() )
                 .Join( db.Table2, t1 => t1.TankID, t2 => t2.TankID, (t1,t2) => new { Company = t1, t2.ExpireDate } )
                 .GroupBy( t => t.Company, (c,e) => new { Company = c Expiration = e.Max( x => x.ExpireDate ) } )
                 .ToList();
```

Best guess at VB

```
Dim tanks = db.Table1.Where( Function(t) t.CompanyId == txtCompanyID.Text.Trim() ) _
                     .Join( db.Table2, Function(t1) t1.TankID, Function(t2) t2.TankID, Function(t1,t2) New Thing With { .Company = t1, .ExpireDate = t2.ExpireDate } ) _
                     .GroupBy( Function(t) t.Company, Function(c,e) New Thing With { .Company = c, .Expiration = e.Max( Function(x) x.ExpireDate ) } ) _
                     .ToList()
```

Comment: do you know how to do this in vb.Net.  I'm new to linq, but I know the syntax between c# and vb is different

Comment: It should be very similar, the lambda expressions just need to be translated to the appropriate syntax.  I think what I've added should work.